# Delete keyword c++

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, destructor

I have a class that has 2 bools and an array of pointers which I allocate on heap.The problem is when it calls the destructor it gives me an error,probably because it deletes too much,I saw it trying to access 0xdddddd and showing me this "Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xDEEEDEEF."

1.How do I use "delete" better,is it because of the operator overload?

2.Also it says that i didn't initialized "QuadTree::childs",why?

```
class QuadTree {
public:
QuadTree* childs[4];
    bool info;
    bool parent;

QuadTree() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
         childs[i]=NULL;
    }
    info = false;
    parent = false;
}


~QuadTree() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            delete childs[i];
    }
}
    QuadTree& operator=(const QuadTree& tree) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        childs[i] = new QuadTree;
        if (tree.childs[i]->parent == 1) {
            childs[i] = tree.childs[i];
        }
        childs[i]->info = tree.childs[i]->info;
        childs[i]->parent = tree.childs[i]->parent;
    }
    return *this;
 }
}
```

So this is the code for adding two trees.I created the overload operator for the next reason,if the node of one tree is white and the other is a parent,i just want to copy the parent.

```
void addTrees(const QuadTree& tree1, const QuadTree& tree2, QuadTree& end) {

if (tree1.info == 1 || tree2.info == 1) {
    end.info = 1;
    return;
}
else if (tree1.parent == 1 && tree2.parent == 1) {
    end.parent = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        end.childs[i] = new QuadTree;
        addTrees(*tree1.childs[i], *tree2.childs[i], *end.childs[i]);
    }


}
else if (tree1.parent == 1) {
    end.parent = 1;
    end = tree1;

}
else if (tree2.parent == 1) {
    end.parent = 1;
    end = tree2;

}
else {
    end.info = 0;
}


}
```

Comment: In the constructor, you are not allocating memory on heap. This is why when the destructor is called there is no memory to free.

Comment: Maybe, it's worth to mention the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). With overloading the copy assignment, you should provide a custom copy constructor as well.

Comment: Maybe, it would be worth to mention the meaning of `info` and `parent`. I wonder a bit about the check for the childs `parent`s in your copy assignment. Actually, `tree` is their parent you get passed into the copy assignment. So, how can there be children without a parent?

Comment: So what info means,is that either the node is black or white(0 for white,1 for black),what parent means is that if it's an end or if it continues to become another QuadTree.The thing is I try to add 2 trees to become one,I will add the code for tree adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `childs[i] = tree.childs[i];` is not doing  what you think it is doing.

You are now referencing the memory that they allocated and no longer referencing the memory that you allocated. Whoever tries to delete this memory  second will have a bad time.

If you want to copy their child into your recently allocated child you will need to dereference the pointer to operate on the object itself. `*childs[i] = *tree.childs[i]`

Comment: IMHO, this adds to [Armin Montignys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423682/7478597). Though I wonder why the assignment handles `info` and `parent` members of the `childs` but not that of `this`. Maybe, I oversaw something...

Comment: This is working thanks!So i was copying the memory of tree.childs[i] to childs[i]?

Comment: @Ax1aL `childs[i] = tree.childs[i];` copies the pointer with two (fatal) effects: 1. The previous pointer in `childs[i]` gets lost (and the memory is leaked if it was not a `nullptr`). 2. The pointer in `childs[i]` and `tree.childs[i]` is now identical and will be freed in `this` as well as in `tree` later -> double free of memory which is prohibited and results in Undefined Behavior (e.g. a crash). In opposition: `*childs[i] = *tree.childs[i];` copies the contents of pointer `tree.childs[i]` to the memory of `*childs[i]` -> i.e. a call of your copy assignment operator for that instance again.

Comment: Thanks!That's what I wanted.And another question,why it says that I didn't initialized "QuadTree::childs".I made them null...

Comment: @Ax1aL You _assiged_ them to null but you didn't _initialize_ them. Initialization happens in the initializer list of constructor. In your case, it will work as it is but, in general, initialization is preferred. Initialization would be `QuadTree(): childs{ nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr }, info(false), parent(false) { }`. (If you left it out, the compiler will use default initialization.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your assigmnent operator.

```
    QuadTree& operator=(const QuadTree& tree) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            childs[i] = new QuadTree;
            if (tree.childs[i]->parent == 1) {
                childs[i] = tree.childs[i];
            }
            childs[i]->info = tree.childs[i]->info;
            childs[i]->parent = tree.childs[i]->parent;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

In these lines:

```
if (tree.childs[i]->parent == 1) {
    childs[i]->info = tree.childs[i]->info;
            childs[i]->parent = tree.childs[i]->parent;
```

`childs[i]` maybe a `nullptr` which is ok for assignment but not ok for dereferencing.

And with `->parent` you do derefence a `nullptr`

Please check for `nullptr` before derefencing.

Comment: The thing is,that's why I added that if statement there,all the nodes are sure to be fulled,if it's a parent,it's for sure that there will be no nullptr for the tree.childs[].

Comment: Yes, but childs[i] itself is a nullptr, and that cannot be dereferenced. Check, if childs[i] != nullptr

Comment: Well,before doing anything I create a new memory on heap for it,to prevent it being nullptr,childs[i] = new QuadTree;.